# had given or gave?

Tags: tense

> Rose kept the promise she **had given / gave** to Charles last year.

Since "kept" is already in a past tense and the promise must have happened earlier, I thought "had given" was the right choice, but apparently "gave" is the right choice. Is the way I learnt it wrong?

Comment: In fact, because of *kept* only, IMO, the answer is *gave.* Had it been 'Rose had kept the promise...' I think it could have been the other choice.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct, and it will depend on location which form is more commonly used.  (I would consider *had given* to be the correct answer but *gave* would be ok.)

*kept* is the imperfect form of *keep*, *gave* is the imperfect form of *give* and *had given* is the perfect form [of give].

If written with the linking word *that* (which then sounds like "better" English):

> Rose kept the promise *that* she had given to Charles last year.

then in this case *had given* rather than *gave* would be the better choice (with the usual caveat of location affecting how people speak).

On the other hand, if broken down into separate sentences as in a conversation:

> Rose kept the promise.
>
> What promise?
>
> The promise [that] she gave [to] Charles last year.

then *gave* sounds better.